# In Illustrator, how do I select every "," on the page?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, typesetting

I have hundreds of files that currently use "," as a decimal place. I need to change them all to "." ie. "9,45" needs to be "9.45". I feel that there must be a selection option to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A quicker workaround to avoid replacing ALL commas would be "Find-Replace" using 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 0....it's 10 F/R cycles BUT you assure you only get number commas not others.

Answer (score 0):

Find & Replace should work for you.

From the menus, choose:

Edit > Find and Replace

[image: find & replace]

Search for all the commas, and replace with decimals. I'd still cycle through them one at a time, unless you are sure there are no commas you want to keep.